# ListView и Custom Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, activity

Не пойму почему с помощью Custom adapter не заполняется список, максимум до чего додумался это до того что ImageView пока статичный и не участвует в заполнении списка, хотя я делал отдельный TextView без лишних обьектов результат один и тот же.

***activity_heroes***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HeroesActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/heroesListView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/heroesListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textNickname"
        android:layout_width="251dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="279dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:text="Nickname"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/heroesListView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.145"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.272" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLvl"
        android:layout_width="111dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
        android:text="Lvl"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/heroesListView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textNickname"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textNickname"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textNickname"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.562" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***list_hero_view***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/heroesImageView"
        android:layout_width="426dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.533"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/wraith_apex_legends" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textHeroView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Wraith"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="54sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/heroesImageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.12"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/heroesImageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/heroesImageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04000002" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***HeroesAdapter***

```
class HeroesAdapter(context: Context, heroes: List<TestHero>): BaseAdapter() {
    private val context = context
    private val heroes = heroes

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return heroes.count()
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return heroes[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return 0
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

           // categoryView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_heroes, null)
        val listheroView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_hero_view, parent, false)
           // val categoryImage: ImageView = categoryView.findViewById(R.id.heroesImageView)
            val heroText: TextView = listheroView.findViewById(R.id.textHeroView)
            val category = heroes[position]

           // heroText.text = category.legends.all.keys.first()
        for((key) in category.legends.all){
            Log.d("HeroesActivity", key)
            heroText.text = key
        }

            return listheroView

    }
}
```

***HeroesActivity.kt***

```
class HeroesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var heroesAdapt : HeroesAdapter
    lateinit var playerIfnAdapt : PlayerInfAdapter

    val listHero = ArrayList<TestHero>()
    private val TAG = "HeroesActivity"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_heroes)

        getCurrentData()

        heroesAdapt = HeroesAdapter(this, listHero)
        heroesListView.adapter = heroesAdapt




    }

    private fun getCurrentData() {
        val api = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(ApiRequest::class.java)

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response = api.herList().awaitResponse()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val data = response.body()!!
                Log.d(TAG, data.toString())

                withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                   // adapter.add(data.global.name)
                   // adapt.add(data.global.platform)

                    listHero.add(data)
                    heroesAdapt.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    textNickname.text = "${data.global.name} (${data.global.rank.rankDiv} дивизион)"
                    textLvl.text = "Уровень: ${data.global.level.toString()}"
                    when(data.global.rank.rankName){
                        "Silver" -> textNickname.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#7A7A79"))
                        "Gold" ->   textNickname.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#E6D600"))
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Возможно не правильно описал ситуацию. В textView (textHeroView) попадает только последний элемент из массива. И получается что ListView не списком идёт а просто с одним последним именем из массива.

Я думаю, проблема в этом фрагменте кода

```
   for((key) in heroes.legends.all){
   Log.d("HeroesActivity", key)
   holder.heroesName?.text = key
 }
```

[image]

Тут логи в которых видно что список куда больше чем просто  одно поле Seer

[image: logs logs screen]

Comment: Одинаковая проблема с разными адаптерами https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1319937/177345

Comment: @pavlofff Да всё верно, я должен удалять этот пост да бы исключить дубликаты ?